# Drag & drop directly via application name in sidebar

Tags: drag-and-drop, spotify, sidebar

I already found a helping demo app "kitchensink" to get an introduction on how to handle drag & drop on an HTML element on a page of my app but I would prefer to fire the event directly when dropping on my apps application name in the sidebar on the left - like last.fm does when dragging an individual track.

Can anybody help to accomplish this?

Best regards
T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the "Application Manifest" section of the Spotify [Integration Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/) for details on what to add in the `AcceptedLinkTypes` key of your manifest. Once you've done that, you need to handle the `EVENT.LINKSCHANGED` event on the application class to react to the drop. Documentation on that can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/2edfee4d46.html).